# How to search partial arabic string using like query in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like

I came across a problem , when i want to search for arabic string it doesn't return any record. English words starts from left to right, however arabic words start from right to left.

E.g following is the string

الحمد لله رب العالمين

if i want to search all records containing the strings  '%لله%' how to achieve this

Technologies used
PHP , MYSQL , Yii

Comment: Is this a problem with like operator (%searchexpression% should match regardless of the reading order) or is this a character encoding issue (either your stored data or your search string is incorrectly encoded and thus they do not match)?

Comment: well they stored correctly in db , because we able to display them on front end

Comment: And what about the search expression?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the search statement in the usual way
viewing in RTL or LTR is something in the view layer and the system is responsible for it.
The data will be stored as it was entered
I think you should be aware of diacritic ( ex: "الشًمس" not equal to "الشمس" )